# How does sample_weight work in SGDClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use importance sampling when I train the `SGDClassifier`. I've seen there is a `sample_weight` parameter in the `fit` and `partial_fit` methods but I am not sure how this parameter works.

Let's say that I have 10 samples and I use an array with 10 weights, will these weights multiply the loss function for the relative sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the relevant code in [linear_model.sgd_fast](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L579-L799), the most pertinent line being:

```
update *= class_weight * sample_weight
```

After each update step the final update is simply modified based on any provided sample or class weights provided.

An example of the high level result can be found in the user guide in [SGD: Weighted samples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_weighted_samples.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-sgd-weighted-samples-py)